# What is the difference in usage between "lethal" and "fatal"?

Tags: differences, adjectives, word-usage

This cropped up when I was in a conversation with a friend. I guess *fatal* must talk of something which has necessarily resulted in death, while *lethality* is more about potential to cause death. Yet I am not convinced by this explanation, because *lethality* is associated with specific agents of death, like injection, dosage of medicine, weapons, etc.

Could someone pin the exact difference in usage between these words? Are the following sentences alright, for instance?

- He has been diagnosed with a lethal type of cancer.
- He died after getting hit by the fatal weapon.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your understanding is already close to the mark. There's a discussion of the [synonyms for *fatal*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fatal) in the American Heritage Dictionary:

> *Fatal* describes conditions, circumstances, or events that have caused or are destined to cause death or dire consequences: a fatal illness.
>   *Deadly* means capable of killing: a deadly poison.
>   *Mortal* describes a condition or action that produces death: a mortal wound.
>   *Lethal* refers to a sure agent of death that may have been created solely for the purpose of killing: execution by lethal injection.

Thus, *fatal* and *mortal* are more often used to describe the immediate circumstances of death, whereas *lethal* is used more to describe agency. For example, you use a *lethal* weapon to strike a *fatal* blow.

Note also that *fatal* doesn't always refer to death: As a word relating to fate and doom, it's applicable to any catastrophic outcome, not just deadly ones. For example, any plan can have a *fatal* flaw, but only deadly flaws are *lethal.*

Comment: [This definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fatal) makes the potentially useful point that *mortal* tends to refer to the past, where *fatal* (which emphasizes inevitability) can reference the past or the future, and *deadly/lethal* tend to refer to the future.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks! That's an interesting alternative take on it. It also emphasizes the inevitability of _fatal,_ which is another subtle difference between the words.

Comment: @BraddSzonye: That's perfect, Bradd. So I guess both the sentences in my example are wrong.

Comment: @Shyam I think “lethal cancer” is fine, but “fatal weapon” is probably better written as “deadly” or “lethal.”

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fatal) also has usage information. Broadly similar to the above, but for *deadly* they emphasise "applies to an established or very likely cause of death", which I think is more accurate.

Answer (score -1):

In 1987, My grandfather decided to brag to me a story about his Military days. Halfway through his story, a fellow soldier from the same Battle/War overheard our talking and decided to correct the usage of certain terms being said by my grandfather.  This is what the man had said..

Something being LETHAL, means it has the "Potential" to create an automatic kill, but is not automatically able to kill. Meaning, it is able to kill, but is not automatically a kill, as in an Allergy, it is potentially an automatic killer, but can be stopped if given a chance.

Something that is Deadly, is already automatically capable of killing. Deadly, means it cannot be stopped from making its kill (aka an unstoppable Kill). Poisons come in Lethal and Deadly, meaning one has the chance to be stopped from making its kill (has a cure or antidote), while the other will be unstoppable (No cure, no antidote).

Comment: What about 'fatal'?