# What does it mean to be "mortally wounded"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

The only source I could find for a definition of this phrase was [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortal_wound), which states a mortal wound "leads directly to the death of the victim. Death need not be instantaneous, but follows soon after." The rest of the article seems like speculation.

The crux of my question is these two points:

1. Must a mortal wound lead to death?
2. Is declaring that something is a mortal wound equivalent to saying that death is certain and unavoidable in the present situation?

For example, if a wound is bad enough that the victim will bleed out unless he receives appropriate medical attention immediately, is the wound a mortal wound? Could the same wound be a mortal wound in one situation and not in another, depending on whether such attention is available? That is, does a mortal wound describe the wound itself, or the result of that wound?

Comment: _He was mortally wounded_ normally implies that he died there or soon after. Otherwise it would not have been mortal. "..which leads directly to the death of the victim"

Comment: Also see   [Is it correct to say “He got a fatal injury in the accident” when there is a possibility that the person’s life will be saved?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/38783),  or   [What is the difference in usage between “lethal” and “fatal”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/115429),

Comment: Is it necessarily an either/or question (re: last sentence)? How about the possibility that `mortal wound` describes the wound itself, in terms of its results?

Comment: I think it is worth adding that "mortally wounded" is used colloquially quite often as is "mortally offended" - this obviously does not have anything to do with death but rather that there is a tendency to exaggerate for effect in today's use of the language.

Comment: *"leads directly to the death of the victim. Death need not be instantaneous, but follows soon after."* I'm not really fond of this definition, especially in the context of fiction. E.g. say I received a wound that *would* have been fatal, but was instantly healed at the last second by a wizard. If I strictly follow that definition, then I would have to dumb down the severity of my wording by using less potent phrasing, all to accommodate an extraordinary circumstance. Near-fatal or near-mortal just doesn't have the same punch, from a storytelling standpoint.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Not only *must* a mortal wound lead to death, but it must *have led* to death. "Mortal" means the victim has passed. "Mortal" does not mean "potentially mortal if left untreated". Because then *every* wound is mortal. You can die from a papercut. In fact Wikipedia goes on to explain just that.

Likewise, when Wikipedia says "Death need not be instantaneous, but follows soon after", it refers to the past, not the future. It means to say that whether or not the death *was* instantaneous, if you can pin it down to a particular wound, then that wound *was* mortal.

And yes, *mortal wound* describes the wound itself. It does not describe the result of that wound. The word for the result is *death*.

Comment: Curious that one can receive a mortal wound, but not have a mortal illness or have a mortal accident: those two must both be *fatal* not *mortal*.  Is it a matter of volition?

Comment: Which, of course, leads onto the question of whether, in a fatal accident, the fatality must occur almost instantaneously, or at least at the scene of the accident, or can it still be a fatal accident if death occurs subsequently in hospital but as a direct or indirect result of the accident?

Comment: @tchrist I've heard the phrase "mortal illness" before.  The medical world uses Mortality and Morbidity Reports to track diseases/etc.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morbidity_and_Mortality_Weekly_Report

Comment: If you mean that 'while there's life there's hope',  so that no wound can be known to be mortal while the victim lives, it may be arguable. But saying that 'mortal' *cannot* be properly used while the victim lives is wrong; http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NDUn87LN8OkC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=%22the+wound+is+mortal%22&source=bl&ots=UaRrEHKmvV&sig=5VQ-pZZaUErOkT78HOoQJmnl9Sk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=x0TIUc6LNsOo0QWIiYHYBg&ved=0CFAQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22the%20wound%20is%20mortal%22&f=false

Comment: Please suggest a replacement phrase since it is wrong: "X was was left mortally wounded by a knife-wielding drunk. If Y had not found him, he would not be alive."

Comment: @aitchnyu I've already suggested alternatives in my answer! In your example, you can simply omit "mortally", since your second sentence says all that is necessary.

Comment: @TimLymington That link only shows that it *could* (or at least *was*) used that way 150 years ago. It says nothing about its *current* usage.

Comment: @TrevorD, if I rightly recall, in the record-breaking days of aviation, record attempts were discounted if they lead to a fatal crash, the definition of fatal crash being someone dying within two days of the accident. Hence the saying, "if no-one dies withing 48 hours it's a good landing".

Comment: I would say that **has led to death, or inevitably will**. A chicken is quite active after its head has been chopped off, but it's a goner from that point on.

Comment: @jmoreno Not necessarily: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_the_Headless_Chicken

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: Mike had most of his head chopped off, that makes a difference.

Comment: Poor Dexter ... he died of a mortal papercut.

Answer (score 3):

As @mplungjan has said, I would suggest that it describes the **result** of the wound. For other contexts you could use expressions like:

> The wound nearly proved fatal (mortal).
>   It would/may have been a mortal wound had he not been treated so promptly.

Unless the wound actually proved fatal ('mortal'), any other attributed meaning would be speculative.

Comment: IMHO, this can undermine storytelling by weakening the reader's mental image of the scene. A near-mortal wound simply sounds less frightening than a mortal one. I feel like there should be a better alternative.

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy: Words are not defined according to whether they help or undermine story telling! The author needs to choose appropriate words - not vice versa!

Answer (score 2):

"Mortally wounded" is used to describe a wound that has already killed somebody.

If used to describe a wound on a living person/animal, then in common usage it would be implied that either you *think* the person is going to die from the wound, or you have foreknowledge that the person is going to die, such as a narrator in a story.

If someone was wounded, but recovered, then another description should be used, such as "critically wounded" or "severely wounded".

Comment: "*Mortally wounded is used to describe a wound that has already killed somebody.*" No, that's not a prerequisite. Did you read the first sentence of OP's post? "Death need not be instantaneous, but follows soon after." I.e. the victim is **not** necessarily dead at the time the phrase is used.

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy: ... and did YOU read the second paragraph of the answer above: "If used to describe a wound on a living person/animal, ..."?

Answer (score 0):

meaning of "mortally wounded as distinguished from fatally wounded" is important in Philippine criminal justice. It's meaning can spell the difference between frustrated and attempted killing. The crime is consummated homicide if one inflicts upon another a "fatal" injury leading to the latter's death. If he survives the injury that by it's nature if left unattended medically, would lead to death, the crime is frustrated homicide.  If the injury is of such character that the victim needs no medical attention to survive, the crime is attempted homicide. In the frustrated phase, all the acts of execution in the crime of homicide has been performed and there is nothing left for the perpetrator to do. While in the attempted stage the assailant has still to inflict a "mortal injury". Hence "mortal" is used commonly to describe injury in the frustrated stage and "fatal" in consummated homicide.